# WP_Query - Bug with multiple post types

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm creating a WP_Query, and I need it to get multiple post types, and it's working REALLY strangely.
I have 3 post types: 'equipo','accion' & 'publicacion'. And my code looks sth like this:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>array('equipo','accion','publicacion'),'posts_per_page'=>-1);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

If I do this, the query only shows the posts "publicacion". If I take publicacion out, it works. Actually any combination that doesn't include that post type, works well. I'm driving crazy trying to understand why this doesn't work.

The Configuration JSON for the custom post types (generated with CPT UI plugin) is this:

```
{
  "evento": {
    "name": "evento",
    "label": "Agenda",
    "singular_label": "Evento",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "delete_with_user": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "has_archive": "true",
    "has_archive_string": "eventos",
    "exclude_from_search": "false",
    "capability_type": "post",
    "hierarchical": "false",
    "rewrite": "true",
    "rewrite_slug": "",
    "rewrite_withfront": "false",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "menu_position": "",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_menu_string": "",
    "menu_icon": "dashicons-calendar-alt",
    "supports": [
      "title",
      "editor",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "taxonomies": [
      "area"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "add_new": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "new_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "view_items": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "not_found_in_trash": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "featured_image": "",
      "set_featured_image": "",
      "remove_featured_image": "",
      "use_featured_image": "",
      "archives": "",
      "insert_into_item": "",
      "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
      "filter_items_list": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": "",
      "attributes": "",
      "name_admin_bar": "",
      "item_published": "",
      "item_published_privately": "",
      "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
      "item_scheduled": "",
      "item_updated": ""
    },
    "custom_supports": ""
  },
  "publicacion": {
    "name": "publicacion",
    "label": "Publicaciones",
    "singular_label": "Publicación",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "delete_with_user": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "has_archive": "true",
    "has_archive_string": "publicaciones",
    "exclude_from_search": "false",
    "capability_type": "post",
    "hierarchical": "false",
    "rewrite": "true",
    "rewrite_slug": "",
    "rewrite_withfront": "true",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "menu_position": "",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_menu_string": "",
    "menu_icon": "dashicons-format-aside",
    "supports": [
      "title",
      "editor",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "taxonomies": [
      "area",
      "tipo"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "add_new": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "new_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "view_items": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "not_found_in_trash": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "featured_image": "",
      "set_featured_image": "",
      "remove_featured_image": "",
      "use_featured_image": "",
      "archives": "",
      "insert_into_item": "",
      "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
      "filter_items_list": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": "",
      "attributes": "",
      "name_admin_bar": "",
      "item_published": "",
      "item_published_privately": "",
      "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
      "item_scheduled": "",
      "item_updated": ""
    },
    "custom_supports": ""
  },
  "equipo": {
    "name": "equipo",
    "label": "Equipo",
    "singular_label": "Miembro del equipo",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "delete_with_user": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "has_archive": "true",
    "has_archive_string": "",
    "exclude_from_search": "false",
    "capability_type": "post",
    "hierarchical": "false",
    "rewrite": "true",
    "rewrite_slug": "",
    "rewrite_withfront": "true",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "menu_position": "",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_menu_string": "",
    "menu_icon": "dashicons-businesswoman",
    "supports": [
      "title",
      "editor",
      "thumbnail",
      "excerpt"
    ],
    "taxonomies": [
      "area"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "add_new": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "new_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "view_items": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "not_found_in_trash": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "featured_image": "",
      "set_featured_image": "",
      "remove_featured_image": "",
      "use_featured_image": "",
      "archives": "",
      "insert_into_item": "",
      "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
      "filter_items_list": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": "",
      "attributes": "",
      "name_admin_bar": "",
      "item_published": "",
      "item_published_privately": "",
      "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
      "item_scheduled": "",
      "item_updated": ""
    },
    "custom_supports": ""
  },
  "accion": {
    "name": "accion",
    "label": "Iniciativas",
    "singular_label": "Iniciativa",
    "description": "",
    "public": "true",
    "publicly_queryable": "true",
    "show_ui": "true",
    "show_in_nav_menus": "true",
    "delete_with_user": "false",
    "show_in_rest": "true",
    "rest_base": "",
    "rest_controller_class": "",
    "has_archive": "true",
    "has_archive_string": "acciones",
    "exclude_from_search": "false",
    "capability_type": "post",
    "hierarchical": "false",
    "rewrite": "true",
    "rewrite_slug": "iniciativas",
    "rewrite_withfront": "true",
    "query_var": "true",
    "query_var_slug": "",
    "menu_position": "",
    "show_in_menu": "true",
    "show_in_menu_string": "",
    "menu_icon": "dashicons-admin-site-alt3",
    "supports": [
      "title",
      "editor",
      "thumbnail"
    ],
    "taxonomies": [
      "area"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "archives": "Iniciativas",
      "menu_name": "",
      "all_items": "",
      "add_new": "",
      "add_new_item": "",
      "edit_item": "",
      "new_item": "",
      "view_item": "",
      "view_items": "",
      "search_items": "",
      "not_found": "",
      "not_found_in_trash": "",
      "parent_item_colon": "",
      "featured_image": "",
      "set_featured_image": "",
      "remove_featured_image": "",
      "use_featured_image": "",
      "insert_into_item": "",
      "uploaded_to_this_item": "",
      "filter_items_list": "",
      "items_list_navigation": "",
      "items_list": "",
      "attributes": "",
      "name_admin_bar": "",
      "item_published": "",
      "item_published_privately": "",
      "item_reverted_to_draft": "",
      "item_scheduled": "",
      "item_updated": ""
    },
    "custom_supports": ""
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to work around this or what might be causing this weird behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you registering these three post types?

Comment: I've created them using the CPT-UI Plugin, they all work more or less the same way.

Comment: Please include some screenshots of the settings you're using with each post type so people here can try and reproduce the bug and help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: There, I uploaded the JSON configuration of the post types. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPML or Polylang, make sure all your custom post types are set to translatable. Had the same issue and this solved it for me.

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer, so your solution can be applied. I.e. sample code.

Comment: There is no sample code. It's a setting in the WPML/Polylang options, where you can turn on/off the support for your custom post types.